# Classes With Friend Functions of Each Other

Tags: c++, friend, forward-declaration

Is it possible to create a class that has a friend function of a forward declared class? If I wanted to create two classes that have friend functions of each other, how would I do that? This attempt fails with the message `invalid use of incomplete type 'class Y'`:

```
class Y;

class X
{
public:
    void a();
    friend void Y::b();
};

class Y
{
public:
    void b();
    friend void X::a();
};
```

I also tried forward declaring `void Y::b();` right after `class Y;` which similarly did not work. Would this example be an indicator of bad design on my part or just a limitation of C++?

Comment: It's hard to say whether something is a good design without knowing what's it's intended to accomplish--but it does seem like a design that would require pretty careful justification, anyway.

Comment: Make either class Y a friend of class X or vice versa. As far as I know C++ does not allows that. By the way, it somewhat suspicious that you need bidirectionnal friendship. You might want to reconsider your design.